# Error al crear conexión segura o redirección https en Safari

Tags: https, safari

Recientemente estoy creando un proyecto donde finalmente todas las direcciones de la url irán por https, y cuando parecía que todo iba bien en Mozilla Firefox, Chrome, Opera al entrar en Safari tanto de Windows como Mac me da este error:

Safari no puede abrir la página "https://www.url.com"
Safari no puede abrir la página porque no puede establecer una conexión segura con el servidor  "https://www.url.com"

En el servidor supuestamente tengo un SSL seguro que se instala automáticamente, quizás no lo estoy usando bien de ahí una de mis dudas y el archivo .htaccess que uso hasta el momento tiene estos datos:

```
# Impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio

Options All -Indexes

# Url Amigables

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^url.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.url.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$ index.php?ruta=$1
```

¿Qué otra opción puedo intentar para solulcionar dicho problema?

Saludos.

Comment: `En el servidor supuestamente tengo un SSL seguro que se instala automáticamente,` ¿A qué te refieres con esto?

Comment: @José Carlos - Kahlito pudiste solucionarlo?? tengo exactamente el mismo problema. Gracias

Comment: Pues se quedó igual ya que contacté con el servidor y me dijeron al no ofrecer  Safari soporte para la versión 5.1 de windows que no lo tuviese muy en cuent, así que me olvidé del tema. Sin embargo ahora al actualizar la web de navegador y con otro SSL parece que va correctamente.

Yo que tu contactaba con el servidor ya que también vi que era un problema de caché con el header y las redirecciones desde .htacess